# What happens if the energy has no lower bound?

Tags: field-theory

In almost all theories that we investigate there is an lower bound on the energy. But is this necessary for a theory to be a good description of reality?

I know from quantum field theory, that in its early days there was the idea of a Dirac sea of negative energy particles. This interpretation was replaced and is not used today, was this also due to the fact that there has to be a lower bound to the energy?

Comment: The absence of a lower bound is normally taken to mean the theory is not physically meaningful and/or the theorist has made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Do you know a book or some other reference where it is explained why such a theory is not physically meaningful? That's what I am basically looking for

Comment: A lower bound on the energy is essential for the stability of matter.

Comment: But why? I need some kind of paper/book as a reference... or a proof ;-)

Comment: If there is no lower bound on the energy, a system can simply transition into lower and lower energy states ad infinitum and would therefore be unstable, and hence not a good theory. This is why Dirac postulated the Dirac sea, he was trying to avoid this problem of instability.

Comment: But still, if energy is conserved you would stay at a finite energy. Then you could argue that we always have dissipation, so that an infinite amount of energy can get out. Then I would argue that this is only possible because the environment has an infinite energy capacity. So what if the environment or the universe is finite? In this case it would still be wired as we constantly pump energy into the universe. Then again you could argue that this rate is slow compared to 'usual' matter dynamics. In this case there could be a connection to the accelerated expansion of space.